# Spring Security configuration not validating user/password from mysql

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

When I login in my app, has to be done a query, to validate if the user exists in the mysql database. But, it is not being done, or if it is being done, I do not have any clue.

I am using this configuration at my spring-security.xml:

```
<beans 
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/home" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/restrict/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/assets/**" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/restrict/js/**" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"  access="hasRole('Admin')" />               
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/administrador.boxml" access="permitAll" />        


    <security:form-login login-page="/login" 
            default-target-url="/organizacao"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
            authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?erro=true"/>
    <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/acessonegado" />  
    <security:session-management invalid-session-url="/login" /> 

    <security:form-login login-page="/administrador.boxml"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
            authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"
            authentication-failure-url="/administrador.boxml?erro=true"
            default-target-url="/restrict/layout.boxml"/>
    <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/acessonegado.boxml" />

</security:http>

    <session-management invalid-session-url="/login.boxml" />

<bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="br.com.kolss.boxml.login.LoginSuccessHandler"/>
<bean id="authenticationFailureHandler" class="br.com.kolss.boxml.login.LoginFailureHandler"/>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:password-encoder hash="sha-256"/>
            <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="SELECT distinct u.email_usuario, u.senha_usuario, 'true' as enabled FROM usuario u WHERE u.ativo=1 and lower(u.email_usuario)=lower(?)"
                authorities-by-username-query="SELECT distinct u.email_usuario as username, p.descricao as authorities FROM usuario u INNER JOIN perfil p ON u.id_perfil = p.id_perfil INNER JOIN escritorio_contabil e ON u.id_escritorio_contabil = e.id_escritorio_contabil WHERE u.ativo=1 and e.ativo = 1 and lower(u.email_usuario)=lower(?)"/>
    </security:authentication-provider>

    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:password-encoder hash="sha-256"/>
            <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="SELECT distinct a.email_administrador, a.senha_administrador, 'true' as enabled FROM administrador a WHERE a.ativo=1 and lower(a.email_administrador)=lower(?)"
                authorities-by-username-query="SELECT distinct a.email_administrador as username, 'ADMINISTRADOR' as authorities FROM administrador a WHERE a.ativo=1 and lower(a.email_administrador)=lower(?)"/>
    </security:authentication-provider>

</security:authentication-manager>
```

This is the process of the login debuging:

1) Login

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIbFM.jpg

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"                   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

    <!-- META CONFIGURATION -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-     8859-1">
    <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="pt-br">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
    <meta name="description" content="boXml é uma ferramenta desenvolvida pela Kolss especialmente para as empresas que necessitam de uma automatização em armazenamento e organização de XML." />   
    <meta name="keywords" content="boxml, xml, armazenamento, organização, sistema, kolss" />
    <!-- // -->

    <!-- OPEN GRAPH META -->
    <meta property="og:title" content="Armazenamos e organizamos seus XMLs. Faça um teste grátis!"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="restrict/resources/images/boxml_og.png"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="boXml"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="Uma ferramenta desenvolvida especialmente para as empresas que necessitam de uma automatização em armazenamento e organização de XML."/>
    <!-- // --> 

    <!-- WEB DESIGN & DEVELOPMENT -->
    <meta name="author" content="Brício Fernandes" />
    <meta name="reply-to" content="bricioweb@gmail.com" />
    <!-- // -->

    <!-- FAVICON -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="restrict/resources/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <!-- // -->

    <!-- TITLE -->
    <title>Login | boXml - Solução em Armazenamento de XMLs</title>
    <!-- // -->

    <!-- CSS LIBRARY -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="restrict/resources/css/foundation/foundation.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="restrict/resources/css/icons/flaticon.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="restrict/resources/css/styles/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="restrict/resources/css/simptip.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="restrict/resources/css/introloader/introLoader.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="restrict/resources/css/slick.css" />
    <!-- // -->

    <!-- SCRIPT LIBRARY -->
    <script src="restrict/js/jqueryNovoTemplate/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- // -->

    <!-- MODERNIZR - FOUNDATION -->
    <script src="restrict/js/foundation/modernizr.js"></script>
    <!-- // --> 

</head>

<body id="login">

    <!-- INTRO LOADER -->
    <div id="intro"></div>
    <!-- // -->

    <!-- SECTION "CONTACT" -->
    <section id="login" class="section">
        <div class="row">
                    <div class="small-11 small-centered medium-7 medium-centered large-5 large-centered columns">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns text-center">
                                <div class="padding-logo">
                                    <img src="restrict/resources/images/boxml_logomarca_invert.png" title="boXml - Solução em armazenamento de XMLs" width="133" height="35"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <form id="form-login" method="POST" action="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_check" />">
                        <c:if test="${param.erro}">
                            Falha no login.
                        </c:if>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns">
                                <label>E-mail:
                                <input type="text" name="j_username" id="j_username"/>
                                </label>
                        </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="row">                               
                            <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns">
                                <label>Senha:
                                <input type="password" name="j_password" id="j_password"/>                          
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="row" style="padding-top:11px">                      
                            <div class="small-12 small-centered medium-12 medium-centered large-12 large-centered columns">                                                                       
                              <input id="btn" title="Clique para entrar" class="submit button  btn-action btn-green btn-big" type="submit" value="Entrar" />
                              <a id="btn" style="margin-right:0" title="Clique para voltar ao site" class="submit button  btn-action btn-gray btn-big" href="home.boxml">Cancelar </a>
                            </div>                  
                        </div>


                    </form>     

                        <div class="row">   
                            <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns text-center">                               
                                <div class="login-footer clearfix">
                                    <span class="left">
                                        <a href="recuperar.html" title="Clique para recuperar sua senha"><b>Esqueceu a senha?</b></a>
                                    </span>
                                    <div class="partner right">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="https://www.geotrust.com/" target="_blank" title="Secured by GeoTrust"><img src="restrict/resources/images/geotrust.png" width="151" height="37" /></a></li>
                                            <li><a href="https://aws.amazon.com/pt/" target="_blank" title="Amazon Web services"><img src="restrict/resources/images/amazon.png" width="126" height="47" /></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>



    </section>

    <!-- // -->



    <!-- SCRIPT LIBRARY -->
    <script src="restrict/js/foundation/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="restrict/js/foundation/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <!-- // -->

    <script>
    // FOUNDATION LOAD
    $(document).foundation();  
    </script>

</body>
```

2) Goes directly to my Failure class. Why? I do not know.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5UkX.jpg

PS: The password has sha256 cryp. So the password I tried with the cryp:

> normal: 123456
>
> with cryp:
>   8d969eef6ecad3c29a3a629280e686cf0c3f5d5a86aff3ca12020c923adc6c92

Even though, goes to failure process.

And my database row is satisfying the requirements of what the query requests.

Am I missing any config?

Spring security version: 3.1
Spring mvc version: 3.2

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check the server log files?

Comment: I am running locally, my jboss console does not display any action. Just goes to the failure class directly.

Comment: Add your login form and which Spring Security version you are using.

Comment: If you are using Spring 3.2 then why do you have 4.0 xsds?

Comment: You have a form and some javascript is this a normal submit or ajax submit? Also the exception should give you some information on why it failed.

Comment: M. Deinum, 4.0 is for the extensions... but u r correct, better change.
I tested and continue the same.

Comment: Looks okay, can you do 2 things. 1) Set auto-config to false. 2) enable debug logging in your Logger for org.springframework.security and when you login, check the logs if there is any exception.

Comment: Thanks We are Borg, I tested, but continue going to the failure class.

Comment: Yes, but check the debug logs, that was the point.

Comment: We are Borg, I checked... well, with log4j I inserted debug in all login classes.

First, my controller redirect without doing nothing to the login page, then after login goes to LoginFailureHandler.

Comment: Well, maybe there is an important information I have to tell, I am doing this login for a second version of an app, the first uses different technology, JSF, no javascript, spring and hibernate.

In this second version I am using jsp, angularjs, spring and hibernate. But  I can not see impact in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not configuring anymore my query in the xml configuration file of spring security.

I created a class implemented by UserDetailsService (org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.*), where I made my query, and in my success class I can manage the rest of the process.

```
String userName = "";
    String autoridade = "";

    SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    if (context instanceof SecurityContext) {
        authentication = context.getAuthentication();
        if (authentication instanceof Authentication) {

            userName = (((UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal()).getUsername());
            autoridade = (((UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal()).getAuthorities().iterator().next().getAuthority());

        }
    }
```